# Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I am using spring security and the default id (user) and password (provided in logs) and my GET Request is working absolutely fine but when I am using 'Post' request getting below reponse -

```
{
  "timestamp": "2023-08-02T07:39:00.159+00:00",
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "path": "/DbUserHandling/createNewUser"
}
```

On Internet I found that we need to disable CSRF for this and it was working absolutely fine after disabling CSRF but my question is 'is there any way that I should not disable that CSRF and my POST request will work'?

I am using SPring-Boot version 3.1.2.

Comment: By including the CSRF token.

Comment: Nope i don't want to include any csrf token bymyself, let spring security do it.
Or if we have the method by attaching any CSRF Token then please provide me.

Comment: You have to send it from the client, there is nothing there that Spring Security can help you with. Only if you use regular form submits and use ether JSP or Thymeleaf it will be automatically included. If you are posting json you need to incude it yourself.

Comment: yeah i am sending a json from postman or swagger-ui, So what 'key' i should use to send and what value?

Comment: You need to send a header named `X-CSRF` which contains the value (which is either present in a cookie or a header depending on your configuration). There are other questions and answers here on StackOverflow that show how to handle that and also [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript) has a special section for javascript applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config HttpSecurity to ignore your request

```
 SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
    return http.csrf(c->c.ignoringRequestMatchers("")).build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your Solution worked but here we disabled csrf check for the corresponding endpoint, so is there anyway that i should not disable that check and still able to call my POST API.